# Problema con input "date" de formulario php a base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla dinamica de eventos conectado a una base de datos. El tema es que queria crear una columna tipo "date" que reciba de un formulario con input type date para poder darle un orden automatico por fecha, pero cuando cargo o actualizo desde mi tabla dinamica, me sale la fecha 1969-12-31.
Adjunto imágenes para que vean!

Les agradeceria si me ayudan!! gracias!!

[image: Tabla dinamica PHP]
[image: phpmyadmin]
[image: codigo]

Comment: Imprime la variable `$sql` para ver cómo se está creando el valor `$f`, da la impresión de que se crea una fecha errónea y por eso inserta siempre la fecha de 1969. Revisa que el ´input` tiene un `name="fechapos"`  . Y, cuando puedas, cambia la imagen por el texto del código, ya que es mejor para ayudarte con el problema. Gracias.

Comment: Sos un crack! solo me faltaba poner name="fechapos", yo solo le habia puesto en input id="fechapos"

Answer (score 0):

Ante problemas de este tipo como primer paso depura tus datos. Si imprimes la variable `$sql` podrás ver si en `$f` está llegando una fecha correcta. Al ver que todas las fechas se agregan como `1969-12-31` parecería que no está llegando valor para el campo fecha  o que el valor que llega no es una fecha válida.

También, ten en cuenta que si recibes el dato de algún elemento de un formulario éste tener una etiqueta `name="fechapos"`, si no tiene esa etiqueta, no estarás recibiendo nada aquí: `$f=$_POST['fechapos']`.